# Google DataProc Presto: how to write Presto query results to google cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, presto, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a DataProc cluster with Presto installed as an optional component. My data is stored in google cloud storage (GCS) and I'm able to query it with Presto. However, I didn't find a way to write the query result back to GCS. I can write to hdfs if I logged in to master node and run Presto commands from there, but it doesn't recognize any GCS location.

How can I write the Presto query results to GCS?

Comment: Presto supports GCS natively since Presto 302 (https://prestosql.io/docs/current/release/release-302.html). What do you mean by "it doesn't recognize any GCS location"?

Comment: Dataproc Presto is PrestoDB not, PrestoSQL.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a Hive external table backed by GCS, for example:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive \
    --cluster <cluster> \
    --execute "
        CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table(id  INT, name  STRING)
        STORED AS PARQUET
        location 'gs://<bucket>/<dir>/';"
```

then insert your Presto query result into the table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, is there a way that can export data without creating a table first? When there are a lot of columns, it would be inconvenient to manually specify the table schema..

Comment: Also, when you said 'insert Presto query result into the table', do you mean with `insert into table my_table select * from tableA;`? If that's the case, I think it's not really using presto for query. It's using Hive to query and doing the insertion. Can you clarify please?

Comment: It's possible to prepare the empty table first with Hive before inserting into it with the Presto query. Alternatively, you may find it easier to just use a `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT` query to export with the GCS location specified for the table